# What is the most idiomatic way of creating a range of indices from a container?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Is there a better way of iterating over the indices of a container than doing something like this

```
for (auto i : view::iota(0, vec.size())
```

Ideally something that would look just like this `view::something(vec)`.

I understand I can write my own function to do this, but was wondering if this functionality already existed. I am also aware of being able to do something like this

```
for (auto [idx, elm] : view::zip(view::indices, vec))
```

---

After some code examination, I have become aware of being able to write this instead `view::indices(vec.size())`, however even though `indices` has `ptrdiff_t` as a default, using `size()` results in it producing `size_t`, and I would rather retain the `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need *only* the indices, then your first is fine.

There also is the older (but no less good)

```
for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
```

If you also need the elements, then your second is superior.

Comment: Warning may occur in the comparison of `int i` and `std::vector::size`. One way to avoid it is `auto i = 0U` ? https://wandbox.org/permlink/WGZe8zUolxmYxRr9

Comment: Part of the motivation for this question is to pipe into other `view`s and also to move the need for a signed-unsigned cast elsewhere.

Comment: @Hiroki, `auto i = 0U` isn't good enough. `vector<>::size_type` is 8 bytes in x64, `0U` is 4 bytes. It's possible the loop never ends. Here's proposal to add `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` literal to C++ standard, so we can write `auto i = 0zu`. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0330r0.pdf